# Making indexing a row number in map_map2_chr function

Tags: r, dictionary

I am not sure how to make diamnond # change:

```
diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  slice(1:6)

output <- map2_chr(diamonds$price, diamonds$cut, 
                   ~paste0("diamond #", nrow(dmonds) ,
                           " sold for $",.x,
                           " and had ",.y, " cut"))
```

I want first output to be Diamond #1, then Dimond # 2, but I am not sure how to do it in `map2_chr`, it is very easy to do in for loof, but I want to learn this function. So far I only get all entries starts with diamond #6

Answer (score 2):

`paste0` is vectorized, you don't need `map` here :

```
with(diamonds, paste0("diamond #", seq_len(nrow(diamonds))," sold for $",price," and had ",cut, " cut"))

#[1] "diamond #1 sold for $326 and had Ideal cut"   "diamond #2 sold for $326 and had Premium cut"  
#[3] "diamond #3 sold for $327 and had Good cut"    "diamond #4 sold for $334 and had Premium cut"  
#[5] "diamond #5 sold for $335 and had Good cut"    "diamond #6 sold for $336 and had Very Good cut"
```

---

To use with `map` functions we can use `pmap_chr` here :

```
purrr::pmap_chr(list(diamonds$price, diamonds$cut, seq_len(nrow(diamonds))),
     ~paste0("diamond #", ..3 ,
             " sold for $",..1,
             " and had ",..2, " cut"))
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to do the same using map function. Is it possible?

Comment: Definitely possible,  Updated the answer.

Comment: thank you, and what double dots mean in front of numbers? I would expect a single dot there? like .x or .y  if I use map2 function

Comment: It is a way to refer arguments passed to `pmap`. So `..1` refers to `diamonds$price` , `..2` refers to `diamonds$cut` and `..3` refers to `seq_len(nrow(diamonds))`. It is explained in `?map2` in Arguments section `.f`.